# How can I automatically extract highlighted text in MS Word 2010 to a new file?

Tags: ms-word

How can I automatically extract highlighted text in MS Word 2010 to a new file? The trick is I don't just want the highlighted text to be extracted. I what the whole page in which there is one or more words highligted to be extraced to a new document. I have a 300 or more pages document with some pages (around 50) that have some words highlighted. I need to print just those pages so normally I go page by page and print any pages that have highlighted words in them. That is why I want those pages with hightlighted words to be extraced to a new document because this will let me print them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If printing is your objective, you could record a VBA macro which does find, then print current page (unless we just printed this page).